# How to sum range of cells with the same formulas in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I got a range of cells that use the same formula:

```
=A1*IF(B1="Yes",1,0)
=A2*IF(B2="Yes",1,0)
...
```

I would like to have one cell with the sum of all cells in a range of `A1..A10`

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want a SUMIF():

```
SUMIF(B1:B5,"Yes",A1:A5)
```